# How do I get a Garmin Cadence Sensor 2 to pair with an iPhone?

Tags: garmin, cadence, sensor

I have bought a [Garmin Cadence Sensor 2](https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/641212). After installing it on the bike and rotating the cranks to wake it up, theoretically I should be able to pair it with my iPhone but it doesn’t appear in Bluetooth Settings. The [documentation is abysmal](https://www8.garmin.com/manuals/webhelp/cadencespeedsensors2/EN-US/GUID-422A313B-3B65-4AFD-9CFB-8A5E4CA02D95.html) and doesn’t go into any useful detail on the pairing procedure. What’s the trick to get it to show up?

(The iPhone is a 12 Mini running iOS 14.2, but I couldn’t get it to work with my iPhone X on iOS 13 either.)

Comment: Try a new battery in the cadence sensor.  There's no telling how long the sensor sat in a warehouse before being sold to Garmin, and there's not telling how long the battery that came with the sensor sat in a Garmin warehouse before being matched with your sensor.

Comment: Actually, what do you mean pair the sensor to the phone? I believe you’d need an app as an intermediary, I.e. you pair the sensor to the phone *via the app*. And while you can use Strava on a phone as a bike computer, I am not sure if it supports Bluetooth sensor connections. They only just brought back BT heart rate monitor connections on their app, and I think they haven’t implemented connections to other sensor types directly on the app.

Comment: iOS Bluetooth Settings shows only devices that have profiles iOS can handle without extra apps. So, heart rate and speed sensors, MIDI keyboards, etc all require a separate app.

Comment: It’s a new battery since I started fiddling with this a couple of months ago. The device wakes up and gives me 5s of green flashes, not the red flashes that indicate low battery. That’s not the problem.

Comment: There’s a bike cadence sensor profile in the BLE standard, which made me think it might at least appear there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Garmin Cadence Sensor 2 will not pair with an iPhone via the Garmin Connect app, nor directly from iOS Bluetooth Settings. You need to use an entirely different app—I have successfully paired it via [Cadence](https://getcadence.app/) and the [Wahoo iOS app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/wahoo-fitness/id391599899).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it could work using their Garmin Connect App.

See Page 5 below.

https://www8.garmin.com/manuals/webhelp/cadencespeedsensors2/EN-US/Cadence_Speed_Sensors_2_OM_EN-US.pdf

See this snippet too:

https://www8.garmin.com/manuals/webhelp/cadencespeedsensors2/EN-US/GUID-E87E78BB-03DD-48C1-AA67-A69E591B01FC.html

However, I think optimally this thing is designed to be used with a bike computer [Garmin Head Unit](https://amzn.to/3qWokog) vs. a phone as I am not sure how it will display the cadence info as you ride. Note I never used my phone as a bike computer so perhaps there is a way to do that.

Comment: You’ll notice the heading of that section is “Pairing the **speed** sensor with your smartphone” (emphasis mine.) The cadence sensor does not appear at all in the Garmin Connect app’s list of devices.

Comment: IIRC Garmin will find all sensors but it’s listed as a number so it won’t say Cadence it will be a number your looking for once paired it. It can be done as I’ve done it and also paired wahoo speed and cadence with Garmin head units

Comment: Neither page 5 of the PDF manual, nor the equivalent web page (they’re exactly the same, it seems?) mentions what software to “pair” the __cadence__ sensor with. If you find the cadence sensor in the list of devices available in the Garmin app I’d love to see a screenshot as it’s not in mine.